# Easy and convenient way to implement custom services

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to implement `Service` base class that is going to be an MVC API Controller with 3 requests `Check`, `Pay`, `PayStatus`. Every request and response has its base properties, and additional parameters as generic class to use individually for each service.

Example:

```
public class CheckRequest<TParams>
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public TParams? AdditionalParams { get; set; }
}

public class TestServiceCheckRequest : CheckRequest<TestServiceCheckReuestParams> {}
```

I came up with something like this yet.

```
/// <typeparam name="T1">Check Request Params</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T2">Check Response Params</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T3">Pay Request Params</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T4">Pay Response Params</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T5">Payment Status Request Params</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T6">Payment Status Response Params</typeparam>
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class Service<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T1>> Check(CheckRequest<T2> request);
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T3>> Pay(CheckRequest<T4> request);
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T5>> Paystatus(CheckRequest<T6> request);
}
```

But this solution with 6 generic arguments seems not so convenient and I am looking for another solution.
Is there any way to use interface like `IServiceParams` in base class instead of all generic arguments, and use implementations in derived classes, or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I will stick with my solution with generic arguments yet, as there are no better solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a Service base class that is going to be an MVC API Controller with 3 requests Check, Pay, and PayStatus, you can use the following code structure.

```
public class CheckRequest<TParams>
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public TParams? AdditionalParams { get; set; }
}

public class TestServiceCheckRequest : CheckRequest<TestServiceCheckReuestParams> {}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class Service : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T1>> Check<T1, T2>(CheckRequest<T2> request) where T1 : class where T2 : class;
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T3>> Pay<T3, T4>(CheckRequest<T4> request) where T3 : class where T4 : class;
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T5>> Paystatus<T5, T6>(CheckRequest<T6> request) where T5 : class where T6 : class;
}
```

You can use the IServiceParams interface in the base class instead of all generic arguments, and use implementations in derived classes, like this:

```
public interface IServiceParams { }

public class CheckRequest<TParams> where TParams : IServiceParams
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public TParams? AdditionalParams { get; set; }
}

public class TestServiceCheckRequest : CheckRequest<TestServiceCheckReuestParams> { }

public interface ICheckServiceParams : IServiceParams { }

public interface IPayServiceParams : IServiceParams { }

public interface IPayStatusServiceParams : IServiceParams { }

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class Service : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T1>> Check<T1, T2>(CheckRequest<T2> request) where T1 : class where T2 : ICheckServiceParams;
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T3>> Pay<T3, T4>(CheckRequest<T4> request) where T3 : class where T4 : IPayServiceParams;
    [HttpPost]
    public abstract Task<CheckResponse<T5>> Paystatus<T5, T6>(CheckRequest<T6> request) where T5 : class where T6 : IPayStatusServiceParams;
}
```

With this implementation, you can use the IServiceParams interface in the base class instead of all generic arguments, and use implementations in derived classes.

Comment: Using your code, in implementation methods are also going to be generic. how it is going to be resolved by model binder like witch params model to use when somebody makes a request to an action ?